# CollectionFS, GridFS and get back file to front?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I had added files to mongodb with GridFS

```
some = Pictures.findOne({name:"Screen Shot 2014-10-20 at 17.34.59.png"})

Object {_id: "t5ykoBS2aRhu99Syd", name: "Screen Shot 2014-10-20 at 17.34.59.png", image:      FS.File}
```

but when I've tried to get file

```
some.getFileRecord()  // Object {}
```

No data. How to get image/file or Url back, from db?

Answer (score 2):

The `some.image` is a `FS.File`, which has the method `url`. That way you can at least get the url to the image, as seen on https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#url

Update: I have a minimal, working example of GridFS, that returns an url (and you can thus show the image on a website for example:
https://gist.github.com/ayonix/a02ed2512bc9070259d3

Comment: I try example in this readme (https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#basic-example) except - no Filesystem - I use GridFS.
Also - I see file in cfs.images.filerecord (by Mongohub).

But request: Images.find() - have 0 elements.
No error when insert, but no elements when try to find

Comment: Have you got `imagemagick` installed and added `cfs:graphicsmagick` to meteor (for the gm method in "thumbs")? Maybe it doesn't catch that error and thus it doesn't get inserted.

Comment: I have trying with imagemagick, without im. No difference, no error has catches

Comment: Have you tried the example I posted? That works for me

Comment: Sorry. I forgot about removing autopublish. No publish - no images. ;-(
Sorry for waste your time